# how to handle select and dropdowns that is inside of a table?

Tags: html, jquery, select, dropdown, bootstrap-5

i am recently making an billing website and i am having issues while creating invoice generator.
when I'm putting any dropdown or select element inside of the table > tr > td ,the dropdown is opening inside of that related td tag.So, it is not visible on the page.

I tried to make the row relative and corresponding dropdown absolute so that it opens outside of the td tag but it is also not working because table tag hasn't have that space remaining below when dropdown opens so. it opens but not visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Billing - Admin & Dashboard Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta content="Premium Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template" name="description" />
    <meta content="MyraStudio" name="author" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <!-- App favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../public/images/favicon.ico">
    <!-- App css -->
    <link href="../public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
<div class="table-responsive col-lg-12">
                                        <table class="table table-centered mb-0 nowrap" id="order-table">
                                            <thead class="thead-dark">

                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">#</th>
                                                    <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Item</th>
                                                    <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Quantity</th>
                                                    <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Price</th>
                                                    <th scope="col" class="border-top-0">Amount</th>
                                                    <th scope="col" class="border-top-0"></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="TBody">
                                                <tr id="TRow" class="d-none">
                                                    <th scope="row">
                                                        1
                                                    </th>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3 "
                                                            data-toggle="select2" id="selectItem" required>
                                                            <option></option>
                                                            <option>INR- indian rupee</option>
                                                            <option>USR-us Doller</option>
                                                            <option>EUV-uk euro</option>
                                                            <option>PWD-Pound</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                            Please select an Item.
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control"
                                                            id="inputQuantity" name="inputQuantity" required
                                                            onchange="Calc(this);">
                                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                            Please provide quantity.
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control"
                                                            id="inputPrice" name="inputPrice" required
                                                            onchange="Calc(this);">
                                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                                            Please provide price per unit.
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input type="number" min="1" value="" class="form-control"
                                                            id="inputAmount" name="inputAmount" disabled>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="NoPrint">
                                                        <button type="button"
                                                            class="btn btn-lg text-center d-flex align-items-center btn-danger p-1 px-2"
                                                            type="button" id="deleteItem" onclick="BtnDel(this)">
                                                            <i class="bx bx-trash"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <!-- <td colspan="6" class="h5 text-center" id="noData">No Data
                                                        Available Currently</td> -->
                                                    <td colspan="6">
                                                        <button type="button"
                                                            class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect waves-light d-flex rounded-pill align-content-center align-items-center justify-content-center col-lg-12"
                                                            id="addItem" form="orderInfo" onclick="BtnAdd()">
                                                            <i class="bx bx-plus font-size-22"></i>
                                                            &nbsp; Add
                                                            Item
                                                        </button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                        </table>
</div>
 
 <script src="../public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/pages/add-table-demo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

this is my code in which I'm having this problem.I have put the select element with selectItem in the td tag of the table

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.